# How many b+ trees does MySQL have when one table has many different indexes?

Tags: mysql, innodb

The MySQL InnoDB engine is based on a clustered index, all records and index data are stored in the index. So I am wondering where the secondary index is stored? In a different b+tree?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The `PRIMARY KEY` (which is 'clustered') is stored with the data in one BTree.  Each *secondary* index is stored in another BTree.  For more details, search this stackoverflow for my answers to similar questions.